# 1 Million documents

Tags: document

If I have 1 million+ tax return documents with SSN as a metadata field. Each SSN can have up to 7 tax return documents. Can I store all 1 million+ documents into 1 library or folder with the assumption that the SSN is required to view the document list results?

I understand there is a 5000 document limit for lists.  It is not the intention to list anything beyond documents for a single SSN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Of course you can, you can add 30,000,000 to your document library. but you need to keep in your mind the **List View Threshold**, you need to add index columns to your list and add views to filter these documents based on these index columns where each view should not get more than 5000 based the filtration that you made.

as example: you can categorize your documents based on type or creation date, then you can add these as index columns to your list, after that you can create some views each one has unique filter to get less than 5000 documents.

**Note:** it is not recommended to change List View Threshold settings, read this:  [The List View Threshold (STOP! Don’t change it!)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/quentin/archive/2014/07/15/the-list-view-threshold-_2800_stop_2100_-don_1920_t-change-it_21002900_.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You can store more than 5000 documents. You need to change default List View Threshold from 5000 to your requirement.

You can change the threshold limit from Central Admin.

Application Management --> Manage Web Applications --> General Settings --> Resource Throttling --> List View Threshold.